# Undefined symbol when importing cythonized c++ code

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cython

I tried to call c++ code from python, using cython in this minimal(ish) example:

```py
# setup.py
import numpy as np
import glob
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  name = "pytest",
  version = "0.0.1",
  author = "Herbert",
  #cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  py_modules = ['pytest'],
  ext_modules = cythonize(
    '_pytest.pyx',
    language="c++",
    sources=['testcpp.cpp'],
    #extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp', '-O3', '-ffast-math'],
    include_dirs = [np.get_include(), '.'],
    #extra_link_args=['-fopenmp']
  )
)
```

```py
# pytest.py
from __future__ import division
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
from _pytest import pyprint

pyprint()
```

```py
# _pytest.pyx
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = testcpp.cpp

cimport cython

cdef extern void testprint ()

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def pyprint():
    testprint()
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void testprint()
{
  std::cout << "C++ at work.\n";
}
```

Then I 'compile' these:

```
#removing possible left overs:
$ rm -rf build/ __pycache__/ _pytest.cpp
$ rm -rf ~/venv3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/{_pytest.cpython-34m.so,pytest*}

$ python3 setup.py clean
.../lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:514: UserWarning: got unknown compilation options, please remove: sources, include_dirs
  warnings.warn(message)
Compiling _pytest.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing _pytest.pyx
running clean

$ python3 setup.py install
.../lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:514: UserWarning: got unknown compilation options, please remove: sources, include_dirs
  warnings.warn(message)
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
copying pytest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
running build_ext
building '_pytest' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I.../include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c _pytest.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_pytest.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I.../include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c testcpp.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/testcpp.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]

### !!!! The next statement shows that the `testcpp.cpp` file should be compiled and linked into `_pytest.cpython-34m.so`:

x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_pytest.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/testcpp.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/_pytest.cpython-34m.so
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pytest.py -> .../lib/python3.4/site-packages
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/_pytest.cpython-34m.so -> ..../lib/python3.4/site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing ..../lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytest-0.0.1.egg-info
```

However, when I run this (from my homedirectory, and not the project directory, to make sure the installed version is used), the dynamic linker can't find the testprint symbol:

```
$ python3 -c 'import pytest;'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _pytest import pyprint
ImportError: .../lib/python3.4/site-packages/_pytest.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: testprint
```

The ... marks the location of the python 3 virtual environment. Notice that if I inspect the .so, the testprint symbol is found:

```
$ nm .../lib/python3.4/site-packages/_pytest.cpython-34m.so  | grep testprint
                 U testprint
0000000000001e60 T _Z9testprintv
```

Why is the testprint symbol not found by python 3?

Comment: Reading the man page of nm, I discovered that the 'U' in front of testprint actually states that it is 'undefined', so apparently it is not in the .so for some reason. The question, why not, even though it was compiled, remains.

Comment: I have a feeling this has to do with code being compiled as c, and being linked as c++. I have no idea why cython decided to do this and how I should configure this, especially since the _pytest.pyx is processed into a .cpp file, which is then compiled as C.

Comment: I'm quite sure the problem is that the .pyx declares a testprint symbol ('U') and that the .cpp defines a _Z9testprintv symbol ('T'), where the _Z9 and v are type signatures. I have no idea why both are different

Comment: I found out that after preprocessing the created _pytest.cpp file, the declaration of testprint equals `extern "C" void testprint(void);`. Apparently the declaration `cdef extern void testprint ()` explicitely creates a c-function, instead of a c++-function. PS: cppdef results in a syntax terror.

Answer (score 0):

All frustration aside, I found a solution. So the `_pytext.pyx` gets processed to `_pytest.cpp`, which after preprocessing (-E switch in g++), declares:

```cpp
extern "C" void testprint(void);
```

This was the result of this cython statement:

```py
cdef extern void testprint ()
```

Basically it declared a `C function` (with symbol `testprint`), whereas a `C++ function` (with symbol `_Z9testprintv`) was defined in the .so file. Since 
`testprint` != `_Z9testprintv` we got a `undefined symbol: testprint`

So how do we fix this? I am clueless about what the best solution is, but this seems to work:

```py
cdef extern from "testcpp.h":
  cdef void testprint ()
```

Comment: I think that probably is the best solution - you're largely expected to use functions from header files like that and the possibility of declaring "originless" extern functions like you originally did is a bit unusual and looks like it doesn't work well with C++ (it might be worth filing a bug report though...?).

Comment: frankly, I'm a 2day expert on the cythonize topic, so I would prefer not to do any bug reporting yet :)